# How to apply Angular Material theme to non-material components?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material2

I am using Angular Material 2 themes for my Angular 4 app.
I have the following themes created in my theme.scss

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@include mat-core();

$primary-color: mat-palette($mat-grey);
$accent-color: mat-palette($mat-blue, 500, 900, A100);
$warning-color: mat-palette($mat-red);

$dark-theme: mat-dark-theme($primary-color, $accent-color, $warning-color);
$light-theme: mat-light-theme($primary-color, $accent-color, $warning-color);
```

And in my style.scss, I have the following

```
@import 'theme.scss';

.dark-theme {
    @include angular-material-theme($dark-theme);
}

.light-theme {
    @include angular-material-theme($light-theme);
}
```

In my HTML I have hardcoded the dark theme (eventually I want to give the user an option to pick one of the two - dark or light)

```
<body class="dark-theme">
    <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

But when I run the app, I don't see the dark colors I expected to see. For instance, if I inspect the body element I don't see any styles at all set to it. Or if I add a h1 element there are no styles set to it. I expected that all the elements inside my body tag will follow the theme's colors. Is that not the case? Should I explicitly mention what colors my non-mat elements need to have?

I don't think the bootstrapping was incorrect. Because when I use mat components like the following, the theme is applied for that component - but the overall background is still not set and hence white.

```
<mat-drawer-container class="example-container">
    <mat-drawer mode="side" opened="true">{{title}}</mat-drawer>
    <mat-drawer-content>Main content</mat-drawer-content>
</mat-drawer-container>
```

Also, what if I wanted to apply a different color from the palette I am using, other than the primary, accent or warning colors? How do I set and use them?

I'm absolutely new to this concept and have only now started understanding what the above code is doing. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm also learning about material.angular.io theme myself. I haven't found the easier way to set like we do with boostrap like `btn-primary` or `btn-danger`. The one I know is to create your own class `.my-primary-background { background-color: mat-color($primary-color) }` and apply that class to what you want to style. Is there a cleaner way? Maybe? Reference: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components#using-colors-from-a-palette

Comment: After some research, I was able to get it going. Theme work only for material components. @Tin I incorporated your solution along with the answer I found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46499768/background-color-does-not-switch-between-light-and-dark-themes-in-angular-materi?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

I think this is what you are missing:

> Finally, if your app's content is not placed inside of a mat-sidenav-container element, you need to add the mat-app-background class to your wrapper element (for example the body). This ensures that the proper theme background is applied to your page.

[source](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#using-a-pre-built-theme)

If you want to apply different colors from the palette, you can use mixins as covered in [this guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components)

Comment: I've applied this class to the div that contains the dark theme reference <div class="wrapper mat-app-background" [class.dark-theme]="activateDarkTheme"> and that do the trick.