# Switching themes in runtime - what is the best approach right now?

Tags: css, themes, vmware-clarity

- I'm building Clarity 3 app (looking forward to upgrade it to Clarity 4 once it's out).
- I don't care about old browsers.
- I guess, I shouldn't use Clarity SCSS as it will be removed in v4

I want a simple way to switch between light and dark themes, which will:

- not include manually copied Clarity CSS code in my files [like this example from docs](https://github.com/mathisscott/clarity-theming-starter/blob/clarity-css-dark-theme-switcher/src/dark-theme.css)
- smooth switching theme without glitches
- every theme will have a small set of its css vars customized (with brand colors and fonts)

I've checked out few answers here, and [this repository mentioned in Clarity docs](https://github.com/mathisscott/clarity-theming-starter), but none of them are compatible with my requirements.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to dynamically switch theme with vmware clarity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47602912/how-to-dynamically-switch-theme-with-vmware-clarity)

Answer (score 0):

You can use native css variables which you can then change via either css itself or javascript since you can address css attributes there. For a smooth switching, that is probably already given by mentioned approach, I would add a transition that is focused on the changed property:

**.html**

```
<html>
    <div id="somediv0" className="theme"></div>
    <div id="somediv1" className="theme"></div>
</html>
```

**.css**

```
:root {
    --theme-attribute-0: black;
    --theme-attribute-1: white;
}

.theme {
    color: var(--theme-attribute-1);
    background-color: var(--theme-attribute-0);
    transition: all 1000ms ease;
}
```

**.js**

```
element.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--theme-attribute-0', 'white');
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--theme-attribute-1', 'black');
})
```

Comment: Yes, but how do I do that with Clarity css vars without copy-pasting them and manually reassigning each variable in js?