# Angular 16 Dark/Light mode with Angular Material

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

Pretty new In Angular (), with this Angular in my machine,

```
Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1602.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular   16.2.3
@angular-devkit/core            16.2.3
@angular-devkit/schematics      16.2.3
@angular/cdk                    16.2.5
@angular/cli                    16.2.3
@angular/material               16.2.5
@schematics/angular             16.2.3
rxjs                            7.8.1
typescript                      5.1.6
zone.js                         0.13.3
```

My Question is, how to implement Dark/Light Mode in a component.
In app.component, it calls header.component that will be emit a toggleValue for theme.
This is my code:

`styles.scss`

```
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

@include mat.core();

// Define a dark theme
$dark-theme: mat.define-dark-theme((
  color: (
    primary: mat.define-palette(mat.$pink-palette),
    accent: mat.define-palette(mat.$blue-grey-palette),
  ),
  // Only include `typography` and `density` in the default dark theme.
  typography: mat.define-typography-config(),
  density: 0,
));

// Define a light theme
$light-theme: mat.define-light-theme((
  color: (
    primary: mat.define-palette(mat.$indigo-palette),
    accent: mat.define-palette(mat.$pink-palette),
  ),
));

// Apply the dark theme by default
@include mat.core-theme($dark-theme);
@include mat.button-theme($dark-theme);

// Apply the light theme only when the user prefers light themes.
@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
  // Use the `-color` mixins to only apply color styles without reapplying the same
  // typography and density styles.
  @include mat.core-color($light-theme);
  @include mat.button-color($light-theme);
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  /* Set the overall container to use flexbox */
  app-root {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh; /* Ensure the container takes the full viewport height */
  }
}
```

`app.component.ts`

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'web';

  /* true light (by default), false => dark */
  activeTheme = true;
  
}
```

`app.component.html`

```
<header id="header">
  <app-header (changeTheme)="activeTheme"></app-header>
</header>

<main id="main">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>

<footer id="footer">
  <app-footer></app-footer>
</footer>
```

`header.component.ts`

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, EventEmitter, Output, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: 'header.component.html'
})
export class HeaderComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  sun = 'light-icon'; // some svg here
  moon = 'dark-icon'; // some svg here

  brand: string = 'MyApp';
  checked = false;

  @ViewChild('darkModeSwitch', {read: ElementRef}) element: ElementRef | undefined
  @Output() changeTheme = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    if (this.element) {
      this.element.nativeElement.querySelector('.mdc-switch__icon--on').firstChild.setAttribute('d', this.moon);
      this.element.nativeElement.querySelector('.mdc-switch__icon--off').firstChild.setAttribute('d', this.sun);
    }
  }

  switchTheme() {
    
    this.checked = !this.checked;
    console.log('Switch theme ', this.checked);
    
    this.changeTheme.emit(this.checked);
  }

}
```

`header.component.html`

```
<mat-toolbar class="header mat-elevation-z6">


  <div class="dark-light-toggle-mode">
    <mat-slide-toggle
      #darkModeSwitch
      (change)="switchTheme()"
      [checked]="checked"
    />
  </div>

</mat-toolbar>
```

Any help or suggesion it`s so appreciated...

Comment: Well you are not doing anything when toggling the theme, than settings some custom variables. You can add a custom CSS class when enabling light mode and apply light theme on that class. There is already a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42533983/5470544. This should still work in a similar way.

Answer (score 1):

There is a mistake in 2nd line in app.component.html:

```
(changeTheme)="activeTheme"
```

An output binding expects an expression. This would work:

```
(changeTheme)="activeTheme = $event"
```

Alternative solution:
You could also implement a setter in app.component.ts (e.g. setTheme()) and use it like this:

```
(changeTheme)="setTheme($event)"
```

**Added**:
My answer was about fixing the Angular part. As @JSON Derulo pointed out, in order to make the whole color mode change work, there are 2 additional steps needed:

- Define css classes representing the two color modes - e.g. ".dark-mode" and ".light-mode" (or define only one and let the other mode be the default).
- Set the right class depending on the flag in app.component.html - e.g. like this:

Remarks:

- This requires to surround the app markup with an extra div. If this is not intended, e.g. the css class could be set by code injecting ElementRef in AppComponent.
- The naming/dataflow can be improved. The flag in AppComponet is called "activeTheme", but it actually only receives true/false. So it would be better to either call it "darkThemeActive", or to send the actual theme names directly from child to parent.

Comment: This will fix the state of the boolean, but still light theme will not be applied, because nothing is done with this boolean.

Comment: @JSONDerulo, there you are right of course. In order to make the whole thing work, it is also necessary, to actually apply the theming based on the boolean flag. I will add this to my answer.